# How can I adjust the fontsize of greek letters only?

Tags: amsmath, fontsize

I am using \amsbook with package \mathptmx.
The fontsize of all Greek letters in math mode is about 12% larger than for non-Greek.
What is it that controls the default size of each font, please?

Comment: Do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (the latter package is essentially a kludge for getting Times also in math with the limited resources available 20 years ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. Not without substantial work, at least.

The package `mathptmx` does

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
```

and if we look at `omlztmcm.fd` we find

```
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}{<-> zptmcm7m}{}
```

Now we can look at the output of `vftovp zptmcm7m`, we see

```
(VTITLE )
(FAMILY UNSPECIFIED)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX MATH ITALIC)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 21074766077)
(SEVENBITSAFEFLAG TRUE)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.277)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.440991)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME psyro)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 37333711466)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME cmmi10)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 1350061076)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 2
   (FONTNAME ptmri8r)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 32105367571)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

at the start and later

```
(CHARACTER O 13
   (CHARWD R 0.630994)
   (CHARHT R 0.4935)
   (CHARDP R 0.016992)
   (CHARIC R 0.082996)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C a)
      )
   )
```

which means that `\alpha` points to the `a` glyph in `psyro` (an oblique version of the standard PostScript font Symbol).

You have to rebuild the virtual font files for `zptmcm7m` by doing something like

```
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME psyro)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 37333711466)
   (FONTAT R 0.89)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

but also all metrics should be changed accordingly *by hand*, so the code for `\alpha` should become

```
(CHARACTER O 13
   (CHARWD R 0.56158)
   (CHARHT R 0.439215)
   (CHARDP R 0.015123)
   (CHARIC R 0.073867)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR C a)
      )
   )
```

and so on for all other Greek letters.

The `mathptmx` package, with the accompanying fonts is essentially a kludge for being able to emulate Times fonts with the limited resources available twenty years ago. Nowadays you can get better results with

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

Comment: egreg Are we saying that Worldwide, and for years, people are putting-up with miss-matching Greek fonts throughout their mathematics?  I've been using, e.g. \newcommand{\lambdasmall}{\scalebox{0.93}[0.93]{$\lambda$}} % and I thought I was plain daft.

Comment: @keith77777 Unfortunately, some document classes (IEEE, for instance) continue to suggest `mathptmx`; some still do `\RequirePackage{times}`, go figure! `:-(`

Comment: egreg Your solution does appear to work except that it gives an error: package clash with package \textcomp (not even present).

Comment: @keith77777 It must be some other package you load

Comment: egreg It appears to be that newtxtext needs to be loaded before libertine.  Anyway, that has fixed the error in my case.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @keith77777 `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`

Comment: egreg Your last offer causes an error each time \libertineSB is called.

Comment: @keith77777 I'm not clairvoyant.